# How to use django-filters to filter a field by a list of inputs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a list of objects that have a country code associated with them, I would like to write a FilterSet class that can receive a list of codes ie. ['US', 'CA'] and will return a  list of the objects that have the country code column set to either of those values.

It doesn't seem like filtersets may be able to do this for me, but its seems like a relatively common requirement? I was thinking maybe it's something like `__in` for the filterset field.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please share more of your code, but probably what your want is someting like
YourModelToFilter.objects.filter(codes__in=['US', 'SA'])

Answer (score 4):

Filterset can do this using [BaseInFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter). Example:

```
class CharInFilter(BaseInFilter, CharFilter):
    pass


class YourFilterSet(FilterSet):
    code = CharInFilter(field_name='code', lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = ModelClass
```